# Graph of implications of topological properties

Tags: general-topology

this might not be the right place for this kind of question but let me try anyway.
I had once long ago found a mind map type graph, which showed many different topology properties and how they interconnected with each other. I however cannot find it or anything resembling it.
If somebody is aware of such a pdf, book or online project, I would be very happy to find this "map of topological properties" once again.
Thanks a lot, and hope this is the right place to ask these kind of questions.

Comment: It's not what you're describing, but you might find $\pi$-Base useful: https://topology.jdabbs.com/

Comment: Thank you, yeah this already has the info I want

Answer (score 2):

Dugundji's *Topology*. Chapter XIV. At the end (p. 311) you can find the diagram "*Diagram of the Main Classes of Topological Spaces Discussed in This Book*". In this text, most classes are assume to be Hausdorff (so that compact implies normal, for example). This gives a richer map that works for most spaces one might work with.

[image: Diagram of the Main Classes of Topological Spaces Discussed in This [Topology by James Dugundji] Book]

The book later adds "without additional hypotheses, none of the implications is reversible".